# return without value in boolean function

Tags: java, android

How can I just use the return keyword without value inside a function that returns boolean, or is there other way?

```
listview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (Conditions...) {
            return;
        }
        //some code
        ...
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: [The contract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent)) says that the boolean return value has a meaning (`true` if you have "consumed the event", `false` otherwise). One of those cases is true; return the appropriate value.

Comment: @mkm, If you want to use `return;` then the function should be void return else you will have to return something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onTouch method returns boolean primitive. you have to return either true or false.

Any method declared void doesn't return a value. It does not need to contain a return statement, but it may do so. In such a case, a return statement can be used to branch out of a control flow block and exit the method and is simply used like this:

return;

[Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: i just want to break out of the if statement. any alternative to return.i tried break; but not working.i need it without it i get indexoutofboundexception.

Comment: @mkm No such alternative.

Comment: if used the outlined statement with void function it will work. any idea with this.

Comment: @mkm if the method is returning void you can use simply return;

Comment: @mkm accept my answer and +1 if your doubts clarified.https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: i know that i have already used it.any idea to exit the function from if.

Comment: @mkm you just have to throw an exception and catch that while calling onTouch. It's not recommended.

Comment: @mkm did you tried throwing an exception? If my post helped you accept answer and +1 to post.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a method with boolean return type then you must return true or false.
In case you want to return some other value, maybe you can change the return type to int.
Then you can return values 0(true), 1(false), or -1(for something else).
However, in this case, you cannot do this since the overriding method requires boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. 
You are overriding a method that is defined in an interface and so you must adhere to the contract that the interface defines. The caller of the method expects to get a boolean value, so you must return one.